# Am I overkilling questions with solutions that are too complex for the OP to understand?

Tags: discussion, answers

Lately, I have quit my SO's professional-debugger position caused by lack of time and a desire to answer only more challenging questions....

Anyhow, I have noticed that I may be [overkilling the questions with solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358183/reverse-order-of-for-each-loop) that are too complex(*not really though*) for the askers to understand...**or** maybe it's my own fault; do I misinterpret a question?

Does the OP these days have to explicitly say: *"I dont care how, I just need it working*" or *"any hack'd solutions are welcome*" in order to answer? **or** should the OP be more clear with the question? Obviously, most of the time the OP does not have a clue about what to expect as an answer which is even more difficult for the answerer to judge the range of the OP's current skills...

Sometimes after putting in the time to research and answer you may find the OP thanking you for the effort but not having a clue about what you just explained to him.

[Help-center's "How do I write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) just doesn't do for me... It's too generalised, it does not really teach you to answer or tell you how and when...

***"...Should or shouldn't I really care about the OP?..."***

I do not do it for the rep. When I am constructing my answer - I want any future reader to be able to understand and adopt the answer/solution. I am not here just to *satisfy* the OP, I am here because I want the answer to help multiple people. Ha, it feels like I have just answered my own question with the last sentence, but in reality how useful is a complex answer going to be to the future reader? Is this predictable? Should I just stop overkilling and force people to take **"No, you can't do that!"** for an answer?

<sup>*linked-question: wasn't aware before answering that the OP was thinking VBA = VB.NET and claiming(yeah, ranting...) he should work for MS with his great ideas, lol*</sup>

Comment: As long as your answer answers the question, then everything is fine. If OP doesn't like your answer, or is afraid of walls of text, then that is not your problem. If OP meant something different then what they actually wrote, then that is not your problem. As long as your answer addresses the problem that is written down, it will be useful to future beings that read the Q&A. A complex answer is much more useful than a code-only answer, in that a future reader can follow the steps, and come to the same outcome.

Comment: @Sumurai8 what confused me it's when I think my solution addresses the problem but I am actually wrong since misunderstanding/misinterpreting the problem. If someone is asking for a solution and they are happy to take `NO` for an answer what is the point of such a question hanging around SO?

Comment: Well, use the comments to figure out the finer details you need for an answer. If a lot of people think that you have no clue where you are talking about, or your answer doesn't answer the question, you'll receive downvotes. If you answer the question and OP changes their question drastically because 'it was not what they meant', thereby invalidating any answers given, then revert their edit and encourage them to rethink what they actually want and make a question addressing that.

Comment: If OP is happy with "no" as an answer, that doesn't mean an insane approach is not useful to anyone else, even if it is to educate that that approach is insane and they should change how they approach the problem, or if they learn interesting mechanics in a programming language they didn't know about yet. It's free knowledge, and as long as it addresses the question, it is valuable to keep it for future people finding the question. (also, I ramble too much)

Comment: If the answer makes a dozen future visitors happy, but the OP not, then well, I would not care about the OP, since this site is there to build a Q&A database to help future visitors, not to please the OP.

Comment: In my opinion, if the question was so unclear that you write a long answer that's completely wrong because you didn't understand the question, that **is** your problem, because you shouldn't have tried to answer in the first place. Leave a comment requesting clarification and/or downvote and/or vote to close as "Unclear What You're Asking" rather than guessing and writing answers. I'd go so far as to say it's actually worse if you guess correctly and your answer's right--this teaches question askers that they'll get good answers without writing good questions.

Comment: What's the issue here? You answer has a score of 7 last I checked (that could be meta effect). It was well received. Personally, I find it *complete* overkill and missing the mark, but what are we discussing? That answer is long. It's more befitting of a blog post. That's not to say it's *not* good for SO, but don't be surprised when nobody has time to read all of that. But, again, that *also* doesn't seem to the problem, because the answer has scored quite well (assuming those folks read it, but maybe that's the "ooh, it has images and header text, it must be good" effect).

Comment: Also, you may want to skip the "hope it helps" part. This is completely irrelevant :)

Comment: @Wooble i think you have missed the point. The answer is not long because the question is unclear. The answer is long because it needs to be long to explain how to achieve exactly what the OP wants. I may have not realized that the OP is actually a noob asking for impossible. I wish I knew that he was asking whether the `for each step -1` is possible before giving a full solution. Anyhow, since i got some upvotes I guess there are people who found both the question and the answer useful.

Comment: @mehow, fine, s/unclear what you're asking/too broad/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Always tailor your answer to the asker's level of expertise.  You wouldn't answer a simple question about method polymorphism in Java with a treatise on Object-Oriented theory, would you?  No, you wouldn't.

You don't, however, have to cater to users with zero experience, nor do you have to guess at the meaning of the OP's question if it is unclear or under-specified.  Askers at Stack Overflow are expected to have a minimal level of knowledge about their craft, and the ability to communicate that knowledge with experts.

Comment: thanks for this answer [I think I see your point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677342/apply-autofilter-in-an-excel-if-character-length-of-cell-is-greater-than-a-limi/24680440#comment38288317_24680440).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should care about the OP.  You should care about the OP's question because that's the same question that future visitors are going to have.

The first thing that future visitors will look for on a question is to check and see if the OP's question matches their own.  If it doesn't match, they're likely to look elsewhere.  By the time they get around to reading the answers, they're likely to have the same question as the OP.

You should make your question complete, **short**, and easy to understand.  The longer your question is, the harder it is to parse and the less useful it is.

---

As it stands, your answer is just too long and too noisy, and it doesn't recognize the [**XY** problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), dealing too much with technique **Y**(iterating in reverse) than with problem **X**(which is removing elements from a collection).

Take a look at the sample you posted and look at your answer and at `chris neilsen's` answer.

**Chris's answer:**

- It takes up about 1/5th of my screen.
- It doesn't give the OP any real code, but it verbally explains the solution
- It actually solves underlying problem, and the OP has understood and accepted the answer.
- It dodges the XY problem by solving problem X with technique Y

**Your answer:**

- It takes about 3 screens,
- It gives the OP a large amount Copy/Pasteable code and
- It gives an explanation which looks tedious to read
- It does not dodge the XY problem because it deals with technique Y rather than focusing on problem X.

Chris's answer ends up being both shorter, and it also gives less to the OP for free at t

Comment: -1 After reading this I feel discouraged to answer at all. The question was answerable and quite clear (*the OP shouldn't be indicating what kind of answer he is looking for* - as he may not be aware of more advanced techniques UNLESS HE IS SPECIFIC) - a comment below the answer saying "I wanted `for each item in collection step -1` should have been included in the Q itself than I wouldn't bother demonstrating anything cause straight out of the box answer would be `NO, you can't`. I truly thought my answer hit the nail on the head. It shouldn't matter whether its 3 lines or 3 screen long

Comment: @mehow Read through the OP's question.  He clearly needed to remove elements from a collection.  The reason why chris's answer was good has nothing to do with the fact that he said "no, you can't"  It's good because it tells the OP how to remove elements from his collection.

Comment: if I was to start with the removing objects from collection using the `for each` I would have picked up on the (OP quote) *`Quite often when I do this it is to remove the object from the collection.`* as I have never seen a `for each` loop in VBA which allows you to remove items from collection. `For each` loops are read-only access to the elements but yeah... I thought the question was **Reverse order of For Each loop** not **removing items from collection using for each loop in the reverse order**.

Comment: @mehow Go back and read the question.  The OP clearly says that the reason he's interested in reversing the ForEach loop is so that he can remove elements from his collection, and this is evidenced by the fact that the accepted answer was the one that gave him a way to remove elements from his collection

Comment: I often write questions where I think I know what my issue is where other users look at the surrounding context and say, why are you doing that? 'X' is a simpler approach. I find this tremendously useful, even when reading questions written by others. Users who explain in great detail how to hack a solution to the complex and wrong approach can also be useful, but in more limited contexts. On the other hand, if I ask about an array and five people jump down my throat about a std::vector, I should also be clarifying why I really need to use an array in my question.