# Should I answer "is it possible?" type of questions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

There are many questions on site which actually ask: *"is it possible?"* which are usually followed by *"OK, great so how do I do that?"* in the comments section. Those automatically raise a "help-vampire" alert.

As far as answering the original question goes you can:

"yes, it's possible. You can do X or Y".

But expanding on X & Y may be as well considered [overkilling it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261439/2140173). We don't want to provide full solutions to poor question to avoid [loss of points, deletions, etc...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270586/when-why-a-question-with-accepted-answer-and-more-answers-is-deleted/).

Ok, so leaving a comment to clarify etc. usually leads to:  *"can you show me how?"* which in turn [makes me want to vote to close as too-broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it). But closing such question would be unfair because the question is in fact still on-topic.

While the question is still a valid (*absolutely on-topic*) but poor research etc. answering it is quite risky.

- Should I answer very briefly throwing a hint or two how to approach the problem? (*I don't want my answer to be considered poor though*)
- Should I vote to close as off-topic (*possibly too-broad*) even though there is no valid reason to do so?
- Should I feed the vampire? (*risky answer*)
- Any other actions I can take that I've missed?

Comment: very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/186381

Comment: Leaving a comment and moving on is a good approach. Say "yes, it's possible using xyz" or "no, it isn't possible due to xyz". If the OP is interested, they can read about the xyz term and find out on their own.

Comment: Sorry if I am sounding dumb right now, or that is incorrect, but... Isn't "design" / "**where** do I start doing X" more a case for [programmers.se]?

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion but that leaves the question unanswered and just hanging meanwhile ruining the statistics for answered to unanswered ratio and makes it impossible to close other duplicate questions because there are no upvoted answers. I see that as a potential problem too.

Comment: To expand a little on my earlier comment. It seems that these questions are acceptable on programmers, given they are asked correctly. They have compiled a very [informative meta-post over there](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start) on why it's **hard** to ask good "where do I start" questions. I think the same reasoning should apply to questions asked here on so..

Comment: @Vogel612 **[Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)** would be a _very bad_ case for Programmers

Comment: FWIW, I have occasionally written "is it possible" questions because I genuinely just need to know if an approach could ever work. I don't need to implement it right now, but I do want to know if that if do X now, then Y is possible at some time in the future. Or if I'm considering between two options Y and Z, I want to know if Z is possible before spending too much time analysing the choice. If Z isn't possible, I might as well just get started on Y.

Comment: quite similar question on Software Engineering meta: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/134647)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you feel confident that the question is really asking how to do something, not if it's possible, then simply edit the question to say that.

If you're unsure if the question is really asking how to do that thing, or if the question really is just asking if it's possible, then ask the author in a comment, again editing the question to ask "how" if that is what the author indicates they really want.

If, as a result of that change, the question becomes too broad, then close accordingly.  If the question is unclear (due to lack of details) then close it for *that* reason.  If it's not too broad, or doesn't meet any other close criteria (and it may well not) then the question has been greatly improved as a result of your edit.

You shouldn't close the question as too broad *without* making the edit, as that makes it rather confusing to other readers (and the author).

---

If you want to answer the literal question asked, ("is it possible" rather than "how do I") then that would also be fine.  It is what they asked, after all.

Comment: Are you suggesting to go on to an editing-war with the OP?

Comment: @mehow If the author rolls back your edit, saying that they *really* just want to know if it's possible, but not how to do it, then leave that as the question, and feel free to post an answer indicating if it's possible without explaining how to do it.

Comment: yea I must agree this is not a bad approach.

Comment: @Servy: A good answer should be backed up with evidence that it's right. "Yes it's possible" but without any indication of how lacks that quality and thus is a bad answer. On the other hand, something like "Yes, it's possible using [feature X of the language] in [manner Y]." is a reasonable answer, I think.

Answer (score 35):

When a person asks "is it possible," mentally translate that to "can you show me how," since that's what the person is really asking anyway.*

Then, deal with the question in the usual fashion.

<sup>*</sup><sub>for what it's worth, I have no idea why people ask this.  It's kind of like these marketing types who know how irritating marketspeak is, but they continue to use it anyway. Perhaps "is it possible" is some in-joke, like a line from "The Big Lebowski" with all the f-words removed.  But if it is, I haven't found the original reference yet.</sub>

Comment: In the same way that you would deal with any other question, after you've changed the words "is it possible" into "can you show me how."

Comment: Ok, as simple as too-broad then?

Comment: If that's what it is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see what you did there.

Comment: +1 for the `*`. I like to be literal with people. If they're going to try to manipulate their way into an answer, I'll give them the exact answer to their question.

Comment: I can vaguely imagine some kind of mental tumbling process that makes "is it possible" seem more 'polite' than "how do i do this" ... sort of like asking "Do you know the time?" instead of "What time is it?" I agree that it's misguided, however, especially in the SO context.

Comment: +1. We need a dictionary that shows common phrases translated to English to help with reading: like "is XXXX possible" -> "please explain/write code for XXXX", "I have a doubt in XXXX" -> "I have a problem with XXXX",... @Servy's suggestion to flat out edit question may be even better approach.

Comment: I don't know, there are times where you don't know if it is possible with `X` or `Y`, and all you need is a bit of direction on where to go.  This will especially happen when business requirements force you to do something that is normally handled by other tools/ languages.

Comment: I'd say you should do more than mentally translate it. If you are going to post a good answer on how to do it, you should also strongly consider editing the question to reflect their *actual* question.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Sure, and it's usually possible to tell, in context, which questions are actually asking "is it possible" and which are asking "how do I do it".  If it doubt, ask.

Comment: @CodyGray: Covered under "Deal with the question in the usual fashion."

Comment: I asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23687903/241211) where I _knew_ the answer might be "you can't do that," and indeed several people said as much (although others showed me how to get what I wanted). Is there a better format I ought to use for those? If I think I have [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230855), what do I do?

Comment: I have many friends for whom English is a second language and have dealt with co-workers, employees and net collaborators with ranges of English skills. I would not make this assumption of translating into "can you show me" as a generalised action. It would depend a lot more on the content of the question.

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR: No.

---

Answering whenever an action is possible or not, without explaining how, is worthless for the rest of us, and possibly a waste of your time having to deal with follow-up questions. This is a prime example of the dreaded XY problem. They ask something but want another.

Whenever I see "... is it possible?" I ask, "why you think it isn't?" or "why you need to know?". Normally, OP answers, "well, I want to foo the bar, using baz" in which case you can tell "yes, the approach you are taking is the correct" or "no, is possible, but you won't get the desired result" which will be essentially what they would want.

Once you get this information, you can edit the question accordingly, even change its meaning, and answer it, otherwise "unclear what you are asking" seems like a fitting close reason.

Comment: I like this way even though it would feel a bit like escaping... But yeah for questions like "is it possible" counter-responding isn't a bad tactic.

Comment: [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25698960/revisions); I asked OP (based on "sufficient research") if there were indications it was or was not possible. It turned out to be, and the question was quickly changed to "send me ur valuable codes". (I first put this under another post, but it's better suited here.)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the question. There are three broad categories:

#### The question is otherwise good

For entirely reasonable questions that are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), include a crisp description of the problem with expected behavior along with a [minimal, complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing effort and research, but that simply phrase their request as an "is it possible?" question, edit "is it possible?" to a concrete, direct question along the lines of "how can I [solve/do/achieve/fix] [answerable problem statement]?", upvote and **post an answer** to it if you wish.

It's counterproductive to be excessively pedantic when dealing with otherwise reasonable posts.

#### The question is unsalvageable

Many "is it possible?" questions fail to meet our normal guidelines and are unsalvageable. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799285/is-this-possible-to-find-list-of-recursive-functions-methods-used-in-project) (entire title and post body included):

> #### Is this possible to find list of recursive functions/methods used in project
>
> Is there any possibility, to find out the number of recursive functions/methods used in the whole application.

You *could* easily edit the post to say "how do I do it?", but playing with phrasing of otherwise unsalvageable questions can be confusing and generally isn't productive even if it happens not to clash with OP's intent (likely, it does).

Vote to close it on sight using the appropriate reason (likely "too broad"), downvote and leave a comment explaining the rationale with a link to the relevant meta posts or help guidelines. **Do not answer** such questions.

#### The question needs a bit of work

Failing the above clear-cut scenarios, the post may exhibit moderate problems beyond the simple "is it possible?" phrasing but is potentially salvageable. In this case, **use your best judgment** on commenting, editing and answering.

Generally, the next step is to post a comment asking OP to clarify their question instead of answering. Typically, focus comments on the non-"is it possible?" issues first.

In some cases, OP will be responsive to requests for clarification, in which case the question falls into the "otherwise good" bucket.

In other cases, OP will disappear or be unwilling or able to rectify gaps in the question. In these cases, the question generally becomes abandoned or reduces to the "unsalvageable" category and can be dealt with accordingly.

---

#### Related topics

- [Why is "is it possible?" a poorly worded question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)
- [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/)
- [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)