# A bit of sarcasm is now offensive?

Tags: discussion

How was my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748505/vb-escape-hash-character) offensive?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Are you not capable to distinguish the difference between offensive and sarcastic?

Just to be clear; [@Robert Harvery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261439/2140173):

> Always tailor your answer to the asker's level of expertise. You wouldn't answer a simple question about method polymorphism in Java with a treatise on Object-Oriented theory, would you? No, you wouldn't.

I thought "OFFENSIVE" is hate speech, racism, etc.....

not an answer that wants you to do something yourself, teaches you debugging, and solves your problem meanwhile... What a misjudge this has caused..

Comment: Just because a question cannot be answered with a good answer doesn't mean you should post a bad one...

Comment: Sarcasm does nothing to help the OP nor does it add anything constructive. Sure, some of us will laugh because of your sharp wit and banter but it may cost us StakcOverflovians.

Comment: Part of the problem might well be in how you pronounce it in your head, and where we put the emphasis when we read it. If they differ , your little sarcastic poke towards the OP (while still trying to be helpful), might well be interpreted completely differently.

Comment: Offensive is subjective. I recently encountered something on SE, along the lines of "I hate userX", that I felt was hate-speech directed at a particular user by name, and others felt it was a playful joke. Interpretations and cultures differ, so being professional is important. If the person in front of you is being rude or dumb, it doesn't justify a bad/offensive answer like the one you wrote. Nothing justifies offensive language.

Comment: Honestly @mehow it's not worth getting hot under the collar about, just leave it and move on.

Comment: @Bart I gave the OP a challenge to try himself and he would then quickly realize "WTF am I even asking?". If by any chance anyone else in the world would ever come across the same problem they would rather be happy solving it the **DIY** rather than reading a boring *you dont need to escape a hash character*...

Comment: @mehow It really doesn't matter. You tried to be "novel" in your approach to an answer. It backfired because it gets interpreted differently than you intended. I wish I could say it never happened to me, but it has and undoubtedly will again at some point. You live, you learn. Move on.

Comment: Is it beer time in the UK yet?  Been there, done that.  Didn't work.

Comment: @HansPassant yep.  A nice pint would do our dear OP good right about now.

Comment: @Will - I meant doing the wrong way around ;)

Comment: I didn't really think this was such a rude answer & it does give some useful information to OP. Sarcastic, sure, but give me teh codez is basically a meme here at this point. Either way, someone was offended, it's really not that big a deal, just let it go. Even off of SO I think most people have the experience of accidentally offending others with something they thought was innocuous. Best thing to do is move on and perhaps reconsider before making that sort of remark next time.

Comment: _"These people don't care how you react; they're looking for the one guy that will actually do their homework for them (some people will). Consequently, your negative \[comment\] will have no effect on the OP, and will only succeed in irritating your fellow community members and alienating new visitors to the site..."_ ([quote source](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3837/31260))

Comment: eh [I give up](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/me-how)

Comment: @mehow It's disappointing that you'd react by saying you're done with the site - you've been a positive member who has contributed a lot of content.  Might I suggest taking a break instead, sometimes it's beneficial to step away for a bit and come back refreshed.

Comment: @bluefeet Until the question quality problem is solved, ragequits from seasoned users will probably continue.

Comment: mehow, if you leave, your last answer should be exemplary, or at the very least, it should be of your standard. I have great respect for your writing. What you write, reflects your standard, and this answer is not how you should be remembered.

Comment: There's a real question hidden in there, how did his VBA editor misbehave to make him think he needed to do this?  Takes quite an expert to figure this out, there are not a lot of leads.  We'll never know.

Comment: Am seeing that recently many of the high reputation users are quitting up.... surely a trouble for SO

Comment: Indeed. I'm sure that Stack Overflow TV will bring them all back. Hmm…

Comment: @CodyGray: Hey! That's offensive sarcasm.

Comment: I don't have any problem with people being sarcastic toward help vampires. moreover, the answer is actually an answer, and someone who searches how to escape hashes will find it useful. +1.

Comment: I don't think it's offensive now that I get it, but at first glance it was reminiscent of those kitten memes where the kitty says "Me wantz nom nom", etc. so it looks a little belittling. But not now that I took time to understand it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I agree [with Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271047/2982225)

> I don't think your answer was particularly offensive, and I suspect a good many readers would agree.

### Your answer is not offensive.

The question asks how to escape the # character.
The answer is that you don't need to escape the # in a string.

You wrote it as a DIY asking the OP to create a string and check if it needs escaping.You even mentioned "Did that *escape* the hash for you?" There is not a single word in the answer that can be deemed as "offensive".

I agree that it is not a good answer, certainly not an answer of your standard, but offensive? - **NO**. It **is** an attempt to answer the question.
If someone feels it's a low quality answer, they should downvote it. But it doesn't deserve to be flagged as offensive.

Comment: Almost every time I see someone say `give me teh codes`, it is said in contempt of someone asking for too much in their question.  I.E. a "help vampire".  Normally it's an abstract person, but in this particular case, there was a specific "help vampire" at hand.  I don't know how you look at that answer, and not observe a clear show of contempt directed at the OP, and shows of contempt are offensive, regardless of whether it's toward a protected group or toward an individual.

Comment: @SamIam I don't think it's offensive either. If I asked a question that turned out to have a simple answer like that, and someone responded with a similar answer, I would try their suggestion then headdesk and laugh at myself. mehow didn't attack the user, it was a *joke* that also happened to demonstrate OP's issue.

Comment: @SamIam: It deserves a downvote, but does it deserve a flag? I don't think so. Community should handle this with downvote and edit if to improve it, but it **doesn't** require a moderator flag as offensive. Flags are **only** for situations which the community cannot handle on it's own. It is an attempt to answer the question. A perfectly valid answer, without any offensive word.

Answer (score 32):

I don't think your answer was particularly offensive, and I suspect a good many readers would agree. It only attracted *one* "offensive" flag (and several downvotes), so I doubt it would've been deleted automatically if a moderator hadn't intervened (truly offensive stuff tends to get the -100 rep penalty + lock), although it would likely have attracted more downvotes.

But it doesn't matter.

Ask yourself, do you *really* want to sit here and debate the exact location of the line between "unhelpful" and "seriously offensive"? Is knowing that going to improve your writing, your attitude, your enjoyment of answering questions here? I rather doubt it.

Folks didn't *like* your answer. Whether they truly thought it *offensive*, unhelpful or merely written in poor taste, the reaction to it was immediate and *visceral*. If it hadn't been deleted, it would likely have attracted even more negative attention, and - given the responses here - probably a fair bit of drama.

You don't need anyone here to tell you all this. You saw the problem almost immediately, and edited to correct it. You could've probably then just flagged it for undeletion, or even just posted the new revision as a new answer.

Either way, you *should have* walked away from that encounter a bit better prepared for the next time, having learned something about how folks are likely to respond to a certain style and phrasing.

Answer (score 25):

A bit of sarcasm isn't bad. Your answer on the other hand is rude, unwelcoming and doesn't help the original poster learn how to ask good questions in any way.

Complaining about it on meta is even worse since now everyone has to read about it and comment when you knew what the correct course of action was from the start.

Please keep answers for answering questions, if you *have* to be snarky at least do it in a comment and add positive directions to help the poster ask better questions next time. Better yet - don't do it at all.

Comment: new user (2 years 2 months) asked 26 poor questions.... yea.

Comment: @mehow So then take a constructive action such as downvoting/close voting/deleting/flagging.  Insulting the user isn't going to help.

Comment: @mehow that does not mean you get to be rude to them, you're very much welcome to downvote them... also, this site has plenty of users who have been here for quite some time but still don't understand how to use the site properly.

Comment: *" if you have to be snarky at least do it in a comment"* ... no, just no. Don't do it. If you have to be snarky, be snarky in The Tavern. Yell at your potted plant. But don't do so on the site.

Comment: @Bart I should probably emphasize the "And add positive directions to help the poster ask better questions next time".

Comment: That part I certainly don't object to @BenjaminGruenbaum ;)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You do that *instead of being snarky* if you want to comment, not *in addition to a snarky insult*.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum being rude? Define that because I haven't said anything rude as far as i remember. This is a Q&A site and my answer did answer the question. I never thought this is about personality and attitudes...

Comment: @mehow I know you were trying to help and I don't want my answer to come off as an attack towards you but there is no way what you said in that answer isn't rude, we can play games all day but you're well aware that your answer was not constructive to say the least. Had I gotten it as an answer I would have definitely considered it rude.

Comment: I'm almost beginning to think that @mehow might actually be oblivious as to why saying `Give me teh codez` to the OP is rude

Comment: @SamIam I bet the OP would laugh himself after following the answer...

Comment: It's rude, unwelcoming, and probably teaches OP to "try it and see" before asking questions that are trivially answered by "try it and see."  So I completely disagree with everything you said.

Comment: @tmyklebu disagree with what who said vba2all?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: You.  AFAIK, vba2all answered the question correctly and probably gave its poster reason to stop and think.

Answer (score 12):

The wording of the offensive flag on an answer is:

> This answer contains content that a reasonable person would deem inappropriate for respectful discourse.

Having material in the answer that is rude leaves them with one of two options: remove it, or edit it.  When the answer cannot stand on its own without the rude material (or that is all there is), it should probably be deleted - the goal of the flag.  Otherwise, it should be edited to remove the offending material.

The threshold for this is for *respectful discourse*.  Stack Overflow and the other sites on the Stack Exchange network is intended for professional use.  That the OP of the question isn't behaving like a professional is no excuse for the people giving answers to not try to maintain the proper level of professionalism that the site desires and expects answers to have.

Comment: Editing the answer -- to use _any other dummy phrase_ -- would have taken about the same amount of time as flagging, and the answer would then be fine.

Answer (score -4):

## Tailor your answer to the asker's level of expertise.

Keep in mind that what you did is something completely different.

An answer tailored to the asker's level of expertise would have been something along the lines of:

> Why don't you try for yourself? Open the immediate window
>   {instructions on how to}.
>
> There you can type `? "foo #"`.
>
> ? does {explanation on what this line does}
>
> As you can see there is no need to escape the character # from a
>   string.

What you did with your answer was:

> Hey you suck, and here's why

And by all means, that **is offensive**

Comment: Sorry but I am not here to babysit anyone. I didn't say "you suck"