# Is Stack Overflow over-polite?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, moderation

Not a dupe of [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/1207195) because (citation from that post)

> ... what can be done to improve the attitude (positivity) of the Stack Overflow users/moderators such that you don't feel scared to ask a question?

That one is about question and answers, nothing to do with "how much comments can be sarcastic" (which more or less is topic of this post).

---

I'm aware of *new* [guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) and I read [this old post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138174/187893) about same topic but in few days I saw two comments I left have been deleted (I suppose they have been flagged because *rude of offensive* and deleted by a moderator).

Well maybe stress is driving me to be more and more rude but now I doubt I can clearly see where that *line* is. One comment (question is now deleted so now I can't find it) was merely citation from question itself plus copy & paste from close reason, something like this:

> "Maybe this is not right place to ask this question", you're right it's not because "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool...".

Another deleted comment from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27402929/1207195) said something like this:

> I thought margin and padding were the tools to control cells spacing, for tabs and spaces also `<pre>` works well (of course I'm joking).

I'm not sure about exact content (I suppose mods can see original comment) anyway the point is: **is this considered too rude**? Is it Stack Overflow community more and more sensible and soon we'll need to prefix all comments with *"I'm sorry but I need to disagree with you, in my modest opinion - if I did understand you correctly - you may be not completely correct..."*. Well I've never been too sensible about comments (unless they're really offensive) then I wonder...where this line is? Should we really *talk* to everyone without irony, jokes and always adding sentences to *mitigate* the fact we disagree with them?

Please note that I'm not really interested in that two comments *per-se* but now I doubt where this *line* is (how to interpret *"If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does."*). **Is Stack Overflow over-polite?** (I would add *examples* and comparisons but I'm sure I'll be absolutely not politically correct).

**EDIT**: a real-world case of what I think is over-politeness: [What do I do when I feel a person has been rude over multiple questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286896/1207195). Why not? Because [we don't need (this kind of) politeness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270903/1207195).

Comment: Your quote of the comment is pretty much right on: *"I thought to space cells you have to use padding and margin, to resort tab and spaces also `<pre>` works...(of course I'm joking)."* And for the record, the flag on it was for "Not Constructive", not rude. I'm not the one who responded to the flag, so I won't comment otherwise.

Comment: This is more about usefulness than politeness or rudeness. Neither of your comments seems to be doing much to improve the posts they were posted under. The  comments weren't rude (at least for my definition of rude), but they weren't particularly helpful either. What would be the value in letting them stay around?

Comment: One specific tip on " irony, jokes" etc.  Avoid joking or sarcasm when saying, "you're doing it wrong" or "you don't know things the rest of us do".  Someone you don't know joking about *your* mistakes or ignorance never feels like laughing with you, but at you.

Comment: I can't find the post, but some find that repeating the close reason text to be unnecessary since it'll eventually come up anyway.

Comment: @ivan not dupe IMO because that's about questions, not politeness in comments

Comment: @andrew thank you for checking. It was (in both cases) _my_ way to explain what's wrong in a light way but well I understand that...

Comment: @jaydles I felt laughing (with, of course)  is lighter than "you are wrong because..." but you're right it's personal. That's why I asked this question...

Comment: @sotirios posting that BEFORE question is closed gives a chance to improve the question, saving it from reopen queue

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I agree. It becomes obsolete after, though.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It makes sense even even if I cannot understand who may flag MY comments as useless...(joking, obviously)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Keep in mind that moderators don't necessarily have to agree with the specific flag that was raised to act on it. A comment that was flagged as rude, for example, may still be deleted if it's obsolete, even if the responding moderator doesn't find anything rude with it.

Comment: The policy is "Be Nice", not "Qualify everything you say". Saying "You are doing it wrong" (preferably with an explanation) is fine. Saying "You're an idiot" is not.

Comment: The problem with jokes, especially sarcasm, is that they're really tough to pull off in a written medium. (Something like 80% of human communication is non-verbal.) Add to that we have a fairly high proportion of non-native English readers here, and you have a situation where it becomes very easy to look like a jerk (however unintentional).

Comment: I laughed when I read the title. I never considered SO anywhere near polite, though I try to keep it that way.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce you're right but I always thought programmers have a weird sense of humor ;)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET exactly! That's why I was surprised they have been deleted. Well finally [my haiku](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278948/is-stack-overflow-over-polite/278952?noredirect=1#comment127214_278952) were not offensive but just useless ;)

Comment: @Compass neither I ever thought it was!

Comment: I would just shrug it off. Comments are second-class citizens, and I would tend to agree that we should err on the deletion side (unless the comment is super-useful of course). It seems you understand that from Brad Larson's answer.

Comment: yes I do, I just _worried_ I've been too rude (somehow I cannot understand) or SO become over-polite politically correct web-site...

Comment: I think it's the first meta post compaining about SO being too little hostile

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271032/2140173

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ probably but I wouldn't see SO hostile however I _worry_ if it will ever be too serious (I don't mean it has to be _stupid_ but ironic).

Comment: @vba4all yes, same _problem_ there.

Comment: I think it's easy to misidentify an uninformed asker making an effort to learn as wrongheaded or not trying. And I think experience with just a few truly zero-effort askers can cause us to give up on questions that the asker will clarify if we tell them how. So another way to look at the situation is not "are folks rude?" but "are folks trying to salvage questions where they can?"

Comment: When a question is so stupid that it's hard not to comment on it, I try to find something similarly stupid that I've done, make the comparison, and call myself stupid. Sometimes I can't think of any such thing, and I also can't figure out how to answer the question without calling it stupid, so I just leave it. It's a bit frustrating, but you quickly forget it when you go to the next question…

Comment: @twotwotwo I agree. If content is not offensive then content (in the ephemeral comments context) is much more important than form.

Comment: @abarnert if you comment just to say "you did something stupid" then I agree with you. If you comment trying to improve question or to help OP then form is less important (IMO). We (most of us) don't say "Mr" or "Sir" when we address someone else on SO...an ironic comment (if its content is helpful to OP) deserves to be posted (aren't you ironic with your colleagues? aren't they ironic with you? are you badly touched by that?).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In the specific case of your first comment, it was flagged as not being constructive. I deleted it because it merely repeated the exact wording underneath the close reason, so it didn't add anything to the question. I typically do this with comments of this style because they're redundant, not necessarily because they could be considered rude.

When it comes to possible rudeness, as has been said many times before, comments are ephemeral things. The guidance we have been presented with is that if a comment is flagged and could be considered rude, we should lean towards deleting it. If there's useful content to be preserved, I might be a little more surgical and try to edit out the rude part of the comment. I try to preserve useful information, but if it's a choice between keeping that and removing a potential insult, I'll remove the insult.

For guidance on what is and is not appropriate, all I can say is that you should remember there's another person behind every post you see here. All people should be treated politely and with respect, even if they have not shown the same respect to members of this site. We can address poor quality content while still being polite to the posters and deal in other ways with those who abuse the community.

Comment: I understand, first comment was useful before question has been closed (as hint to improve it) but meaningless later. I guess 2nd one was too _abstract_ to be useful. Nothing about rudeness. Oh MY comments have been flagged as USELESS?! How come?! LOL

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Yeah, the flag on the first came after the question was closed, so I regarded it as more of an "obsolete" flag. Like I said, this happens regularly after questions are closed.

Comment: And once a comment is flagged; even if the particular stated reason doesn't apply, we'll still delete it if some other predefined criteria applies. Because of their ephemeral nature (and that their resolution doesn't affect metrics we use to determine post quality), we're quite liberal handling comment flags. Much more so than post flags.  If/When SE Inc ever uses comment flags for quality metrics, we'll change that policy. Until then, it's far easier to dismiss/delete than split hairs.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I understand that and I completely agree. In this case I didn't think about "not constructive" flag and I thought they have been flagged "rude or offensive".  Who may ever think his comments aren't pearls, haiku, people should print and frame?

Comment: I often view old threads - and it's nice not to see dozens or hundreds of off-topic comments.  I'm just looking for the answer, and while the 'conversation' may have been valuable at the time, 2 years (or even 2 days) afterward, it just leaves a lot more stuff to wade through.  I'm looking for the answer, and any user contributed, on topic, and helpful responses.  Conversational comments can always go.  When an answer has 2 comments about the answer, it's great.  When it has 11 other comments you have to wade through, it's not so great.
It's why I come here and not forums for help.

Comment: _"All people should be treated politely and with respect, even if they have not shown the same respect to members of this site."_ I think this is where many people disagree with you (I'm not saying it is or is not a majority), and why there is such discord on SE about how nice to be in certain situations. In my culture, respect is earned; or, at the very least, you can disearn it pretty quickly by not showing it yourself to others. Otherwise great answer.