# What do I do when I feel a person has been rude over multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, support

I've seen this person (I'm not sure if I should be pointing fingers here so I'll keep his identity "unknown" for now) be rude (or what I would consider rude anyway) over multiple comments. He sometimes provides comments that try not to help a user, but basically point out that "the other person doesn't know what he's doing". I've been called "a bad example spreading bad practices, like an infection" (after some discussion). To me that is really going overboard. Do I just go around and flag all of the posts I consider rude (I'm not sure they are all really rude in any case, and I might be biased because of what occured before)? Is there a way to report a user for "rude" or "misbehaving" conduct perhaps? Or maybe there is and I don't have enough reputation for it.

The person in question is a very knowledgeable person from what I can gather from his profile. And I'm very sure he knows what he's talking about.
My main gripe however is that he just, instead of trying to provide constructive feedback, leaves comments like "You don't understand **this and that**". Without providing any support for his statements etcetera. It's not overly obvious he places these comments a lot, but enough for me to notice over some time.

I hope I'm at the correct place here, I don't use meta very often because I never have a question for it. Let's just hope you guys can provide me with some answer.

**Edit**
Okay so aparently it's expected to provide the case in question, so I'll oblige. Mind you I found these without much effort (just a few of the first that I encountered)

1. The rude comment towards me has since been removed, but it was here: [How do I organize this list into mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723097)
2. Profile with comments: https://stackoverflow.com/users/727208/tere%C5%A1ko?tab=activities&sort=comments
3. "You don't know what you're doing" comment (**update:** comment has been removed): [Where should redirects be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141328/mvc-where-should-redirects-be-done/28141987#comment44663894_28141987)
4. Comments without reference (no big deal I know, but just thought I'd place it here anyway, **update:** comment has been removed); [PHP entity class example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766400/php-entity-class-example#comment43952707_27766400)

**Edit 2**
Mind you I already advised/told him that I thought those kind of comments were useless (literally, so that might have ticked him off?). Something along the lines of "Those kind of comments are IMO useless".

**Edit 3**
All comments I have discussed in this question have since been removed. Please keep this in mind when replying.

Comment: On Meta; it's typically good to include specific statements, even if you don't attribute them to a person.  We like data and evidence; and without that, it becomes a "from what it sounds like..." instead of what it actually is. It's even better where you link to the posts where that happens, even though that does kill the anonymity, it does allow us to see these comments in context and see what the issue really is. If you're not comfortable doing that, I understand. In that case; don't bring it up to meta at all; and just flag with a custom flag and let a moderator know what is going on.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thanks for your comment. I've updated my question with a few examples. They might not be the worst in hindsight, but I still feel it could/should be looked in to?

Comment: I can understand both sides of the argument. To be honest the terseness is probably bore out of frustration they experience from the questions / answers they see day in day out. It can sometimes be a thankless task, you just may have caught them at a bad time.

Comment: FWIW its *piqued* not peeked

Comment: @Lankymart yeah I agree, it can be frustrating to see question X for the nth amount of time. Then again, I always try to stay respectful. IMO just saying these things isn't helping anyone. If comments aren't helpful, why place them?

Comment: @Plutonix Didn't know that! I learn something new every day ;) Is it okay if I make off with an "I'm not a native English speaker"? ;P

Comment: @Bono I'm a native English speak and I didn't even know that. [Here is the source for that if you are wondering](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101450/is-it-peek-peak-or-pique). It appears that your first link a mod already removed the rude comments.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Though we are reasonably sure there were rude comments there, we don't know if the one(s) OP meant are that, as the mod summarily purged it all.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes I meant those (specifically one among those).

Comment: @Bono: Hm, maybe I wasn't clear enough. We know rude comments were purged, but we don't know whether the comments you spotted *for themselves* were rude. Or at least whether the comments starting it were. Both your resction causing an escalation, and the starting comment already being bad are likely there. (And I'm not trying to judge.)

Comment: Looks like a smart guy that knows what he's talking about, not somebody that gets featured at meta often.  Unfortunately not always taking the time to explain what he knows, that can look rude.  Probably doesn't take much more than a private email from a moderator.

Comment: @Deduplicator Ah gotcha! I can say this (you'll just have to take my word for it). He commented (paraphrasing here) first on OP's question with "You should learn some basic OOP practices first." I told him that those kind of comments are IMO useless, since the OP specified that he was just starting out and trying to wrap his head around it. He then went on the say (paraphrase): "All the more reason he shouldn't be involved with something as complex as MVC", to which I replied that it's never too soon to learn, and that it can't be bad to learn on early. Then he became rude (comment in OP).

Comment: your description of the rude person reminds of me of everyone who is active under the `c` and `c++` tags.

Comment: If someone says "You should learn basic OOP".  You can take it as, "well, that was rude", or you can take it as, "does he have a point?"  I dont see anything inherently rude here. No bad words, no direct insults.  If you feel you *know* OOP, then perhaps your post is not worded to reflect that.  Take a hard look at your post in that case, not other people.

Comment: I toned down what he said because i couldnt fully remember it. It was definitely unsupportive. That was also not the rude part. The rude part was "you're an infection". It was also not me who he told to learn OOP but the person asking the question. Please read more carefully next time :)

Comment: How rude of you to correct me. ;) Sorry I got the wrong end of it.  My point remains however.  Its a matter of perspective, as others have said, if its egregious, flag it, otherwise treat it as what it is, a random comment by a random person on a random post on a random webpage.  Not worth the time to make a response.

Comment: @paqogomez Sorry 'bout that, I tried to put it as softly as possible :P Thanks for the tips, I'll take them to heart as best I can (always tried most of them any way :))

Comment: When I saw the [tag:mvc] tag I at once knew who you are talking about =oP

Comment: Not read the full comments stream, but if the behaviour is persistent, flag it with a custom message, and explain the history. I did so on a high-rep user at the start of the year, and for _extremely_ abusive behaviour (including clearly implied threats of physical violence) they received a month sin-bin.

Comment: FWIW Bono, I've addressed this individual a number of times regarding his terseness, to no avail. I went through a short phase of flagging things from him that were IMO quite reportable, but a moderator declined one, so I didn't carry on further.

Comment: @SamIam You're thinking of H2CO3, right?

Comment: @halfer Alright thanks for the heads up. Glad I wasn't the only one thinking that :)

Comment: -1 - I see absolutely nothing wrong with his posts or comments - to me he sounds like he knows what the hell he is talking about - respect him and learn from him and move on.

Comment: Rudeness has a systemic cost that is hard to quantify but important. Is a user worth keeping around because he provides correct answers but turns off a lot of people? SO measures answers quantitatively but obviously cannot measure the systemic cost to the community. I'll just observe that in other organizations (businesses, clubs) where a very competent person hurts the culture or morale of the team, the normative action is to fire the person rather than ask the team to grow thicker skin.

Comment: @JonH: I don't think competence is the issue here. I think it is fine for someone to take exception to terseness, in general - it's subjective admittedly - but to ask someone to not just tolerate it but to respect it as well is a stretch.

Comment: I read most of this guys' posts - he is far from mean and he has a great understanding of the mvc architecture...actually many of you could learn from this guy.  He's probably sick and tired of answering the same ridiculous questions that many OPs could just google.  Cut him some slack.

Comment: I think I know this *type* of person

Comment: Define rude. Was he actually rude, or did he just offend your delicate sensibilities?

Comment: @JonH Being sick and tired of it doesn't give you carte blanche to be rude. If he's sick and tired then he should take a break from those questions, or else vote to close them with no comments at all. I'm tired of a lot of the questions I see in the Javascript tag but I don't believe it gives me any kind of exemption to what is proper behavior.

Comment: @Chris Hayes - I still don't see it as rude

Comment: @JonH I didn't mean any disrespect to him at all. I did say in my question that he seems very knowledgeable and he knows what he's talking about. I'm more referring to the comments he sometimes leaves on some people's questions. They are _sometimes_ not very supportive, and in my specific case downright rude (I don't find "you're a bad example spreading bad practices like an infection" to be polite to say the least. Especially since I was communicating with him in a very reasonable manner).

Comment: @Bono - What you posted is far from rude.  Asking if someone understands or knows OOP is not rude.  He's a serious guy, and he shows it in his posts.  You guys might want to understand that some people are just serious about their work and they know a lot about it.

Comment: FCo I just read your activities tab, can you point out where he is rude to you?  I saw "please indent your code", to me that isn't rude.

Comment: @JonH There's nothing wrong with him saying to OP that he needs to improve his OOP skills, it's the way he put it (in my example I toned it down). I went on to say that it was not a very usefull comment since OP specified that he was still starting out. Again, I didn't consider that rude, just not useful. What I found rude was the remark specically aimed at me.

Comment: This is unfortunately all too common among coders in real life and even worse in the digital realm.  The difference here is that this a free and open community and no one is FORCING you to answer.  If you can't be nice and actually help someone don't answer.  Far too many meta-trolls, rep harvesters, and other try-hards on these days.  I've cycled through various accounts, but I fondly recall an early era where people were more excited about crowd-sourcing knowledge.  Now it's just another popularity contest or resume point (23,000 rep on SO, look at me!)

Comment: @FCo not sure if you're being ironic/sarcastic or serious, but I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @JonH I'm serious about my work, and I'd like to think I know a lot about it. That doesn't allow me to go around saying things like "you're a bad example spreading bad practices like an infection". If I said that at work I'd be fired on the spot, and I'd deserve it. If somebody insists on making such comments, we're better off as a community without them, regardless of their level of expertise.

Comment: @JonH Sorry, I didn't mean he was being rude to me. I meant to say that he is rude to other people in his comments, using derogatory phrases like "even a beginner should be able to reason" when the question regards something the user does not know, and is clearly not being lazy and knowingly not "reasoning." The comments I was referring to have been flagged and deleted, so I guess I was right.

Comment: The classic 715 upvotes and 13K downvotes kind of guy

Comment: I've looked at the first two pages of comments from this user, and I find nothing rude at all. The one that comes closest (have you tried hiring a developer), could have been rewritten as (please post some code), but it's not far off.

Comment: ITT: different people with different standards of what is rude and what isn't.

Comment: @tohster _Is a user worth keeping around because he provides correct answers but turns off a lot of people?_ If the kinds of people he turns off are the ones who would end up question-banned anyways, then we should give the user a goddamn medal for weeding out crap at the source. Following your team analogy, if some people want to join who are unable to contribute anything to the team's goal (which in our case is creating a repository of useful programming knowledge), but take away resources (=time it takes to look at their crap) then the correct action would be to remove _them_ from the team.

Comment: Related: [Is Stack Overflow over-polite?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278948/1207195). Hey guys...are we going to be **so** sensible? I'll cancel my account the day I'll need to prefix any commnet with "In my modest opinion I think I should kindly disagree...". Come on...

Comment: Incidentally, consistent rude behavior [does not go unnoticed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)

Comment: As BoltClock said there each one has his own _threshold_ about rudeness (but about this I agree with JonH and John Sanunders). _Incriminated_ user may seem _arrogant_ (citation from his own post, I think he has a good knowledge and he's bored to see too basic RTFM/Google questions) and Aducci may be right but **we're here to "judge"** (with votes) **knowledge not pleasantness**.

Comment: @Machavity: I'm probably alone in this but I actually quite liked that guy. Ok, he could be hellish blunt at times but he knew what he was talking about.

Comment: I offer it more as a note that a high reputation person can get the banhammer (or temp banhammer in this case). I have no idea what he did to get said banhammer either (but I was the subject of one of his blunt tirades once). The person in the OP is equally blunt but also highly knowledgeable about a lot of subjects. It's hard not to hang around SO and also be cynical about some topics sometimes. It's just a question of how far they choose to push it.

Comment: @l4mpi sure, some rudeness can get rid of the parasitic user.  But it's a blunt instrument, so the actual systemic cost is:  it also causes well-informed programmers to decide not to spend time answering questions on SO, which then  becomes self-reinforcing.  To extend the analog, if you kick out the freeloaders on a team, you may feel better about getting rid of parasites, but your celebration would be pyrrhic if you've created a culture that attracts unpleasant people and repels good guys.

Comment: This post sounds like a bunch of sour grape complaining, I'm voting to close it as everyone has their own threshold of what may be rude vs what isn't rude.  It's really opinion based.  I find the person being questioned a smart, intelligent guy who knows a lot more on the said topic than the OP of this question does (no hard feelings).  That being said it may sound like he is harsh when in reality he isn't.

Comment: @JonH I don't agree that this should be closed. I agree with you that my opinion on rudeness may differ from yours, but that is not what the question I asked is about. The question is what one should do if they find someone has been rude over multiple questions (lets keep aside if that is actually the case here). Everything around it is just subjective, but the current and possibly new answers can still provide an insight as to what one should do. I also don't feel that this question (what to do) is similar to others, unclear, too broad or sufficiently off-topic as defined on SO. Thanks, Bono.

Comment: @JonH if you think the question can be edited in such a format that it would be better suited I wouldn't mind adjusting it so.

Comment: @Bono - I think you need to stop being a drama queen, the guy you marked as being rude is not rude...and I'm not the only one saying it.  Several others have the same opinion...so you going out and marking him out is just as bad.  To top it off you want to continue the discussion even when people have mentioned the threshold is different to everyone.  You can continue to disagree, but the great thing about this system is that it allows me to cast my vote for/against the topic at hand.

Comment: @JonH I don't think I'm being a "drama queen" at all. I think I've been more than reasonable. I even _let_ him be unknown on my original post, I have no desire at all to besmudge his reputation. You say people agree with you, but I also have people here agreeing with me. So who is in the right? As I said I won't mind editing the original post to make the person at hand anonymous again, so it won't hurt him in the future. I also have agreed several times that the treshold is different for everyone, and I might even be biased. I was just hoping to have a reasonable discussion about it.

Comment: @JonH Anyway, I hope I've been able to convey my meaning/opinion about the matter. If the post were to be closed I guess there's nothing to do about it. I don't agree with it, but as long as it doesn't get deleted I'm fine. I'm sorry if I've been going overboard to you or anyone else who has problems with the thread, apologies for that.

Comment: @JonH: _it may sound like he is harsh when in reality he isn't_. I think you hit the nail on the head there fella. I'm making the fairly obvious assumption that this guy is not a native English and therefore (for him) writing _"You don't understand X"_ is a perfectly legit translation of what he is thinking, whereas a native English speaker would probably write something like _"You have misunderstood how X works."_ None of the comments in his profile strike me as rude at all. For me, the OP is simply confusing brevity with rudeness.

Comment: Oops, obviously I meant _this guy is not a native English speaker ..._ - too late to edit.

Comment: @TheBlueDog I've have already mentioned numerous times I don't find "You don't understand X" rude. I don't know how many more times I have to say that :/ I also mentioned (in OP) that all his comments I have supplied have been removed, so the ones I pointed at as rude/useless have been removed. I'll just stop replying to this post from now on, because it's kind of getting repetitive.

Comment: Your question body states: _My main gripe however is that he just, instead of trying to provide constructive feedback, leaves comments like "You don't understand this and that"_, so you've just successfully contradicted yourself there. As to _it's kind of getting repetitive_ - yes, you are. Let it go man.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Yes, by that I meant unconstructive, not rude. As I clearly said. I'm letting it go now ;)

Comment: Ah, so you actually meant something other than what you typed - see how easy it is? I rest my case. :)

Comment: IMO "you're doing it wrong" is the go to phrase for someone who can't articulate the strengths of one method over another, and is a smell for blindly applying practices where they might not always be applicable.  That aside, I don't think the **intention** is to be rude, but it's definitely off putting.

Comment: I've had a couple of arguments with this guy too. Currently, I try to avoid him as much as possible, because he gets on my nerves.

Comment: Haha, tereško is the Gordom Ramsay of MVC. His comments can be taken as abrasive, you can read a "tone" in what he says when he's going to contradict you -- you're probably just adding that tone, but he might even actually be insulting you. In any case, it doesn't matter. I am not suggesting you "get thicker skin", but I am suggesting that you not take it to heart. You're focusing on the delivery, focus on the content. After all, he might be saying mean things, but he's actually helping you -- how mean could he really be if he's there talking to you, helping you, for free? Focus on content!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For flagrant stuff you flag it.  For a pattern you either collect a list of the examples of worst behavior and go to chat and mention it to mods; or you ask the user in question to go to chat and talk to them.  Ask them to consider either not leaving a comment or being more constructive if they do.

(I didn't look at the links you provided).

Comment: A little clarification for the flag. If it is just one instance then flagging as rude or offensive is fine and moving on. If multiple, flag one with a custom message for the moderator including a few of the others so they can deal with it as a set as opposed to individually as they may not notice the pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that. I'm wondering however about how effective it will be for me, a lowly 1800 pointer, to adress someone of 30000+ points though. I guess it shouldn't matter, but I would imagine one could just shrug it off as they have probably been very active for very long. I doubt my advice would be taken to heart. It's definitely worth a try though (just as a btw. I did comment this to him, along with the OP of the question, that placing these comments were useless).

Comment: @Bono - High reputation doesn't give you a free pass to insult people. It's been our experience that higher-reputation members are more likely to respond positively to polite comments about their behavior, so I'm not afraid to engage someone about this. The key is to keep a calm tone, because anything perceived as an attack can cause things to go in the wrong direction pretty quickly.

Comment: In addition to the actions mods have recommended for this site, develop a thicker skin. In professional life you will be extremely lucky if you do not encounter at least one or two extremely and gratuitously abrasive but higher-ranked colleagues! Learning to manage them, and your own reactions to them, is at least as important as being able to explain MVC.

Comment: IMO "learning to manage them" does not mean ignoring and developing a thicker skin. It means raising these issues up. The reason those people keep on doing what they do is that people more likely switch jobs then actually do something.

Comment: `High reputation doesn't give you a free pass to insult people.` I've been lied to! All these years of work for nothing! :(

Comment: @eis: Certainly it means escalating things... *iff* you are fairly sure of your ground, and it's worth it. Remember, you might just be too sensitive; Misconstruing brevity (especially in criticism directed at your work) as rudeness seems a fairly common failing.

Answer (score 11):

People who are not native English speakers may translate their way of speaking into English quite literally. People from Eastern Europe (or from Holland, like myself), may sound rude to native English speakers, but often it's in no way intended like that, and it's just a way to express a sincere advice or concern. Additionally, due to lack of any facial expressions and body language, it is very easy to misinterpret the tone of a post on any online medium, so please be aware that you may misunderstand his intentions.

That said, I've had a couple of arguments with this particular guy, and I doubt if this explanation fully applies to him. nevertheless, I think the best advice is to flag those comments that are really too rude, and for the other part try to be understanding and forgiving. If you find he gets on your nerves, just try to avoid questions he is active in. There are plenty others.

If you are to comment on his behavior, be sure to use the right tone of voice. The lack of context also applies in the other direction, so a short comment might be misinterpreted as an attack. Try to imagine how one might interpret your criticism. It's almost impossible to be *too* polite, but very easy to be unintentionally rude.

Comment: Thanks Golez, I think I'll do that from now on. On a side note; I'm from Holland as well, so I get what you mean 100%

Comment: And almost the same last name. ;)

Answer (score -28):

Just ignore them. A lot of people in IT and who work with computers are 'on the spectrum' as they say and lack social skills. :-)

Comment: Sorry to be so harsh, but it's true. Very technical IT people have a tendancy to be highly intelligent, a bit weird and occasionally lack certain social graces. These traits are exacerbated by Internet discussion forums. You often see answers like f 'Oh you're so stupid! Everyone knows that in the System Z instruction set, the CVD assembler mnemonic is 1 of 2 instructions that operates from left to right instead of right to left!' posts in response to a simple question.

An actual insult was probably not intended; it's just the way it comes across.

Comment: I'm really afraid but I have to kindly disagree with you. Please accept my poor personal opinion but this is just a **stereotype** without any decent solid evidence. I never had such impression and I see _rude_ people everywhere. Yes technical people (IT or not) may be little bit more _direct_ but this (to me) looks like a bar-style sentence more than a meta-SO question...

Comment: I don't totally agree with you since based on my experiences the case is that the IT people aren't just generally too interested being social and when they do talk, they do have manners. And still your answer isn't actual solution for this IMO. The important thing is that other users might get influenced by these comments and it can affect their behavior in a negative manner.

Comment: That's fine - most people on SO give helpful, polite answers and a few don't. Most people in IT are normal and a few...aren't. I've worked with some right odd people. Generally nice, but odd.

Comment: Downvote for ignorant hatespeech.

Comment: down vote because ignoring a harmful behavior that is not isolated is harmful itself IMHO.

Comment: _I've worked with some right odd people_. Don't even get me started. At the last company I worked for the IT **manager** left on Friday night and came back as the IT **manageress** on Monday morning. :D

Comment: @TheBlueDog you can't say job there is boring...

Comment: That is so true, but really would you expect up votes on SO meta post for this! ?

Comment: Downvote, because first you said "A lot of people in IT [...] are 'on the [autistic] spectrum'" then, probably realizing the awfulness of your answer, went on to say "Most people in IT are normal and a few...aren't.", which is arguably an even more ignorant answer. For a self-declared "normal" person, you have a lot of manners to learn.

Comment: They can also lack a sense of humour.