# User making unkind comments in the [regex] tag

Tags: discussion, unfriendly-or-unkind, regex

There's a frequent user of the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag who often posts unfriendly/unkind comments and, at one time, even post an answer that is basically just ranting. I flagged those on sight and most, if not all, were deleted.

I'm not sure if the mods warned them, but this disruptive behaviour has been going for quite a while now. What should we do with this?

Comment: If you are seeing rude content, then flag it as such. If the user is being rude, and repeatedly, then the moderators will reach you it to the user and they will receive restrictions.

Comment: @ThomA As far as I'm aware, their account haven't been suspended. Hence this post.

Comment: that doesn't change the answer, flag it.

Comment: So what are you expecting the community to do here, compared to the moderators who have, presumably, handled your flags and marked them helpful. (You have checked the flags have been handled, right?)

Comment: FTR, you  nor we get to decide who needs to be suspended.

Comment: Also, what do you mean exactly by "rude"? Can you give an example of such text, without identifying the person?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286896/what-do-i-do-when-i-feel-a-person-has-been-rude-over-multiple-questions/286902#286902

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Some of them are personal attacks on another frequent user of the same tag (without specifying the name) regarding that user's behaviour of downvoting (based entirely on assumptions I believe) and dupehammering in the same tag.

Comment: @InSync - I see two options. You can either provide explicit examples of these comments or flag the comments and allow the moderators to handle them between their team and the user saying the comments. But “regarding that user's behavior of downvoting“ sounds like a user who should be ignored by all parties involved and any inappropriate comments automatically flagged. A user complaining about downvoting and closing of a question as a duplicate often in my experience will only introduce toxic behavior into the community

Comment: Related: from *[What should we do when one person tries to delete every duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/#comment827145_405460)*: *"I admit that I (a fairly high rep user) am afraid to post questions in the regex tag. My first question in that tag got attacked (and I deleted it). I was a ~30K rep user at the time. Since then I have felt that you needed to be really really sure you had an extra extra good and worthy question before posting one in the regex tag. (Basically, if a tag could be considered "unfriendly", then that tag is."*

Comment: cont' - See also [the linked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/405460).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If enough comments are deleted as rude (or harassment) in a short period, mods get an autoflag. However, this greatly depends on how fast mods are handling the flags, so you really should also leave a custom mod flag (on a post from this user, not a comment) if you think there's a recurring problem so it doesn't fall through the cracks.

Note: you can't possibly know if this user was warned since they may have received a mod message without a suspension.

Comment: It's also worth noting that all comment flags are automatically marked "Helpful" if the comment is deleted for any reason (including deletion of the post it's under). This means that a helpful comment flag may not mean that a moderator saw your flag and handled it. This is yet another benefit of using post mod flags which are guaranteed to be seen by a moderator before being marked as handled.

Comment: " flags are automatically marked "Helpful" if the comment is deleted for any reason (including deletion of the post it's under)" - that sounds like a bug? Like, I can imagine *some* cases where flagging a comment could "help" a mod identify that the corresponding post should be deleted; but that isn't generally why the flag was raised.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't know if it's a bug, probably more like an oversight. From a mod perspective, comment flags are also like second class citizens compared to post flags. For another example, consider the fact that there is no "helpful but no action" button for comment flags—a mod must delete or edit the comment to mark the flag as helpful (which is why you shouldn't use comment flags for any reason other than "delete this comment").